# Copy Files on Same Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write powershell Script which will create backupfolder on same Path where Application exist and need to copy the folders & files into backupfolder before deploying. Below are the command was using to perform but am getting error

```
$Source = "C:\XYZ"
$BackupFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $source_$(Get-Date) 

Copy-Item -Path $Source\* $BackupFolder -Force
```

> Error: Cannot copy item C:\XYZ\Backup_18-02-2017 on to itself

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried admin rights

Comment: `$source_` is a valid identifier name. Use `$($source)_` or ```$source`_```

Comment: William - I didnt get your question, If you are asking about the running Powershell with admin rights then yes the account which is running script has admin previliges

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Copy-Item $Source\* $BackupFolder -Exclude $BackupFolder
```

That will eliminate the folder that you are copying *into* as a source that is being copied from.

Answer (score 0):

Variables can contain underscores. The following works and displays the string "asdf"

```
$a_ = "adsf"; $a_
```

Your `New-Item` cmdlet call should have failed since `$source_` is not a variable and would return null. This is default behavior for PowerShell. When I run your code as is I get the following:

```
New-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '02/18/2017 22' does not exist.At line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$source_$(Get-Date)" -what ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (02/18/2017 22:String) [New-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

So I would have expected your folder variable to be null. [wOxxOm brings this up in comment as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322150/copy-files-on-same-directory-using-powershell#comment71797886_42322150)

Several options to address what I am sure is the partial source of your issue.

```
$BackupFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$source`_$(Get-Date)" 
$BackupFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$($source)_$(Get-Date)" 
$BackupFolder = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path ("{0}_{1} -f "$source, Get-Date)
```

You will still have to try and exclude this folder from the copy as well like [Keith Hill's answer is telling you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42322423/3829407)

> ```
> Copy-Item $Source\* $BackupFolder -Exclude $BackupFolder
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
 $Source = "C:\XYZ"
 $Destination="{0}{1:yyyyMMdd}" -f $source, (Get-Date)
 New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Destination

 Copy-Item -Path $Source\* $Destination -Recurse -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly. You want to take `"C:\XYZ"` and backup into the same directory called `"C:\XYZ\backup_$DATE"`. What you will actually do is create a loop that will break once it reaches the max 248 characters. If we use the `-exclude` option then we can exclude the backup directory `"C:\XYZ\backup_$DATE"`.

This function will do the trick and also gives you error handling.

```
Function Get-CopyDirectory{
#####################
# Dynamic Variables #
#####################

$Date = Get-Date -format ddMM-yyyy
$Exclude="Backup*"

####################
# Static Variables #
####################
$AppPath = "F:\Test\"
$BackupPath = "$AppPath\BACKUP_$Date\"

if (Test-Path $BackupPath) {
Write-Host "Backup Exist" -f Cyan
}
else 
{
Copy-Item "$AppPath\*" $BackupPath -Exclude $Exclude -recurse -verbose
}
}
CLS
Get-CopyDirectory
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If you want to accept it as an answer that would be cool.